# Miri complains about UB when initializing and manually dropping MaybeUninit

Tags: rust, undefined-behavior

I am writing code to initialize an array of [`MaybeUninit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/union.MaybeUninit.html)s and drop all initialized elements in case of a panic. Miri complains about undefined behaviour, which I've reduced to the example below.

```
use std::mem::{transmute, MaybeUninit};

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        let mut item: MaybeUninit<String> = MaybeUninit::uninit();
        let ptr = item.as_mut_ptr();
        item = MaybeUninit::new(String::from("Hello"));
        println!("{}", transmute::<_, &String>(&item));
        ptr.drop_in_place();
    }
}
```

Error message produced by `cargo miri run`:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: trying to reborrow for SharedReadWrite at alloc1336, but parent tag <untagged> does not have an appropriate item in the borrow stack
   --> /home/antek/.local/opt/rustup/toolchains/nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/ptr/mod.rs:179:1
    |
179 | pub unsafe fn drop_in_place<T: ?Sized>(to_drop: *mut T) {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ trying to reborrow for SharedReadWrite at alloc1336, but parent tag <untagged> does not have an appropriate item in the borrow stack
    |
```

As far as I can tell, this is exactly how `MaybeUninit` is supposed to be used.
Am I using the interface incorrectly and invoking undefined behaviour, or is Miri being overly conservative?

Comment: If you swap the `let ptr = ...` and the `item = ...`, or if you remove `ptr` and call `item.as_mut_ptr().drop_in_place()` directly, then the error disappears.

Comment: @kmdreko It works in this example, but in the actual code I'm writing this is not possible since `drop_in_place` is called in the `Drop::drop` implementation of a helper struct, so I'm just trying to understand the cause of this error better.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is actually completely unrelated to `MaybeUninit` and can be boiled down to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut item = 0;
    let ptr = &item as *const _;
    item = 1;
    // or do anything with the pointer
    unsafe { &*ptr; }
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=670606dcce4e6077b29018ef4ba2122e)
Which throws the same "undefined behavior" error when run with Miri. [From what I could gather by reading their reference](https://github.com/rust-lang/unsafe-code-guidelines/blob/master/wip/stacked-borrows.md), it seems like Miri has some metadata that keeps track of which pointers are allowed to read an item, and when you reassign that item, the metadata is wiped. However, reassigning values shouldn't change their memory address, so I would say that this is a bug with Miri and not UB.

In fact, changing `ptr` to a `*mut i32` then using `ptr.write` instead of the assignment actually gets rid of the UB warning, which means it's probably a false positive.

Comment: Rust's aliasing rules seem (based on for example the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/aliasing.html)) to not be clearly defined, meaning that there are a number of cases where code may or may not be UB. This seems like one of these cases, in particlar because `item` is being modified directly while being referenced by a pointer. Miri seems to intentionally call this UB (i.e. not a Miri bug) based on its stacked borrows model, but I think that it's a case of "undefined if it's really UB", so I think avoiding the cause of this error and trusting Miri is reasonable here.

Comment: Writing to the value with `ptr.write` doesn't give a UB warning but writing through a mutable reference does, so something is strange here.

Comment: I'd say this is expected. You're trying to circumvent the borrow checker, but your code is essentially equivalent to: `let mut item = 0; let ref = &item; item = 1; println!("{}", ref);`. Note that `unsafe` is not intended to allow you to do things that are forbidden in "safe" Rust, but only to allow you to do safe things when the compiler can't prove that they are safe.

Comment: By the way, I don't know if it has an effect here but Miri don't tracks raw pointers very precisely by default. I would suggest enabling the `-Zmiri-track-raw-pointers` flag as explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/rust-lang/miri#miri--z-flags-and-environment-variables).